DPDK Connect my own app to network interface created by dpdk-testpmd
My Linux server has only one NIC. I try to create virtual network interface using dpdk-testpmd:
sudo dpdk-testpmd -l 0-1 -n 2 --vdev='net_tap0' -- -i

After executing show port stats all I see this interface. But if quit from interactive mode I don't see this interface via ip link show.
How could I connect my own DPDK app to this interface? What should I add to my app or pass specific parameters?
